# How can set accessibility identifier in attributedPlaceholder

Tags: swift, xctest

I have the given piece of code

```
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: Strings.test,
                                                             attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: ColorTheme.test])
```

How I can set an accessibility identifier in attributedPlaceholder so that I can later use the containing string in the UITest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give accessibility identifier to your textfield. Then you can get the placeholder text via property.

```
let textField = XCUIApplication().textFields["textFieldIdentifier"]
let placeholderText = textField.placeholderValue
```